# Ultra-Beginner Python FizzBuzz ... Am I missing something?

Tags: python, beginner, fizzbuzz

I just started programming in Python this morning, and it is (more or less) my first programming language. I've done a bit of programming before, but never really did much except for "Hello World" in a few languages. I searched around for some Python FizzBuzz solutions, and they all seem significantly more complicated then mine, so I think I must be missing something, even though it works correctly. Could you guys point out any errors I've made, or things I can improve?

```
count = 0
while (count < 101):
    if (count % 5) == 0 and (count % 3) == 0:
        print "FizzBuzz"
        count = count +1
    elif (count % 3) == 0:
        print "Fizz"
        count = count + 1
    elif (count % 5) == 0:
        print "Buzz"
        count = count +1
    else:
        print count
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: Only slightly related to your question but this pages contains a few tricks quite interesting if you are starting to learn Python : http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/19dir2/whats_the_one_code_snippetpython_tricketc_did_you/ . One of them leads to a pretty concise (and quite obscure) solution of the Fizzbuzz problem : `['Fizz'*(not i%3) + 'Buzz'*(not i%5) or i for i in range(1, 100)]`.

Comment: Nice solution!  To actually print the items one per line, as most Fizzbuzz questions require, not just show a list of results, this needs to be: `print '\n'.join(['Fizz'*(not i%3) + 'Buzz'*(not i%5) or str(i) for i in range(1, 101)])`.  Also note the 101 - `range(1, 100)` returns 1 to 99.

Answer (score 45):

### Lose the useless brackets

This:

```
while (count < 101):
```

can just be:

```
while count < 101:
```

### Increment out of the `if`s

Wouldn't be easier to do:

```
count = 0
while count < 101:
    if count % 5 == 0 and count % 3 == 0:
        print "FizzBuzz"
    elif count % 3 == 0:
        print "Fizz"
    elif count % 5 == 0:
        print "Buzz"
    else:
        print count

    count = count + 1    # this will get executed every loop
```

### A `for` loop will be better

```
for num in xrange(1,101):
    if num % 5 == 0 and num % 3 == 0:
        print "FizzBuzz"
    elif num % 3 == 0:
        print "Fizz"
    elif num % 5 == 0:
        print "Buzz"
    else:
        print num
```

I've also renamed `count` to `num` since it doesn't count much, is just a number between 1 and 100.

### Let's use only one `print`

Why do 4 different print, when what is really changing is the printed message?

```
for num in xrange(1,101):
    if num % 5 == 0 and num % 3 == 0:
        msg = "FizzBuzz"
    elif num % 3 == 0:
        msg = "Fizz"
    elif num % 5 == 0:
        msg = "Buzz"
    else:
        msg = str(num)
    print msg
```

### Light bulb!

`"FizzBuzz"` is the same of `"Fizz" + "Buzz"`.

Let's try this one:

```
for num in xrange(1,101):
    msg = ''
    if num % 3 == 0:
        msg += 'Fizz'
    if num % 5 == 0:       # no more elif
        msg += 'Buzz'
    if not msg:      # check if msg is an empty string
        msg += str(num)
    print msg
```

Copy and paste this last piece of code [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/pgbovine/python/tutor.html#mode=edit) to see what it does.

Python is a very flexible and powerful language, so I'm sure there could be other hundred and one different possible solutions to this problem :)

### Edit: Improve more

There's still something "quite not right" with these lines:

```
if not msg:
    msg += str(num)
```

IMHO it would be better to do:

```
for num in xrange(1,101):
    msg = ''
    if num % 3 == 0:
        msg += 'Fizz'
    if num % 5 == 0:
        msg += 'Buzz'
    print msg or num
```

There! Now with:

```
print msg or num
```

is clear that `num` is the default value to be printed.

Comment: **Let's use only one print** would work well without converting `num` to a string. It's as if you were already anticipating the need for the conversion on **Light bulb!**? Or maybe it was the purity of keeping `msg` a string?

Comment: @Tshepang: yeah I know, but it would have been more strange to have a `msg` variable that one time is a `str` and another an `int`. Also it isn't a very good practice to have a variable that could have different types. So I'd say that is the **following of the good practices that will lead you towards the light bulb :)** [Edit: Yes, I'd like to think it was number 2.]

Comment: One interesting exercise - what if you want a space between Fizz and Buzz, and no newlines but rather commas. ie `1, 2, fizz, ... 14, fizz buzz, fizz, ...`

Comment: You reach the best solution about half way through this post and then start making it cuter and less readable.

Comment: @MikeGraham I disagree. I think the last version is very readable. Honestly I think appending Buzz to Fizz when n is divisible by 3 and 5 is part of the reason it's in the question in the first place, written as it is. The `print msg or num` is very pythonic in terms of "do this otherwise use the fallback". If it were another language you might explicitly set the output for msg.

Comment: @JordanReiter, the fact that there is a cutesy solution is an important part of fizzbuzz -- people who avoid it have shown good sense. The "A for loop will be better" is plainly more readable than the final solution, which unnecessarily is cute and subtle and less plain. If someone didn't know what the code was supposed to do, they would very, very likely understand precisely what it does quicker reading the "A for loop will be better" solution than the final solution. Code should be as simple as possible.

Comment: We'll just have to agree to disagree. If I were interviewing, I'd immediately follow with: "I've changed my mind. I want 7 instead of 5, and instead of Fizz I want Fooz". In the loop solution, you have to rewrite 5 lines of code; in the "custesy" solution, you only have to rewrite 2 lines of code. The "straightforward" solution includes repeating yourself: you check whether something is divisible by 5 twice and you print "Fizz" (on its own or as part of another word) twice. Can we at least agree that the "Let's use only one print" is *far* better then calling print numerous times?

Answer (score 7):

Your code looks fine.  It certainly works.  The only thing I'd say about it is that you are repeating the incrementation in all `if` blocks.  You could just move that out of and after them and you'll achieve the same thing.

```
if (count % 5) == 0 and (count % 3) == 0:
    print "FizzBuzz"
elif (count % 3) == 0:
    print "Fizz"
elif (count % 5) == 0:
    print "Buzz"
else:
    print count
count = count + 1
```

You could also condense the `if` conditions a bit if you recognize that values of `0` are considered `False` and non-zero is `True`.  You're testing if they're equal to `0` so you could just write it as

```
if not(count % 5) and not(count % 3):
    print "FizzBuzz"
```

I would however not do your loop like that using a `while` loop but instead use a `for` loop.  Then you wouldn't even need the increment statement there.

```
for count in range(0, 101):
    if not(count % 5) and not(count % 3):
        print "FizzBuzz"
    elif not(count % 3):
        print "Fizz"
    elif not(count % 5):
        print "Buzz"
    else:
        print count
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll have to play around with this!

Comment: Also one thing I'll include here, your first condition could be replaced checking if the number is a multiple of `15` instead of `5` and `3` separately.  But what you have is still perfectly fine as they're both logically equivalent.

Comment: One quick question that is slightly off-topic: aside from reducing lines-of-code, is there a reason you prefer the 'for' loop rather then my 'while'? Do you find it more readable? Would most experienced programmers prefer your method as more readable? I only ask because to me it seems harder to read, but that could be because it contains concepts I haven't covered yet.

Comment: Yes it is indeed more readable IMHO.  Any programmer should know what a `for` loop is and what it's used for. Given some variable, the body of the loop will be run for every value in a given collection. A `while` loop isn't quite as clear. Given _some_ condition, the body of the loop will be run as long as the condition is met. It isn't as clear whether that condition will be met as it can be affected by a number of factors. It could change at any point within the body. With a `for` loop, there is only one possible way for the "condition" to change and that is it reaches the end of the body.